# (linux) terminate running script

Tags: linux, kill-process

**linx terminate running python script** , what I know for kill process is that type `kill program_ID`, but this time I'm not sure how to do, and also don't know the key word to describe or search this problem on web

image in case someone wanna see:
https://ibb.co/xJZ2sQJ
https://ibb.co/Yjgcwwx

---

- I'm inside the command prompt :
  (I wrote while loop, so not sure how to stop, I type 'q' also not work)

```
(venv) joy@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python 2.py
^X
:q
q
quit()
quit(q)    
kill
```

- .py script

```
import cv2

# 1.creating a video object
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# 2. Variable
a = 0
# 3. While loop
while True:
    a = a + 1
    # 4.Create a frame object
    check, frame = video.read()
    # Converting to grayscale
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # 5.show the frame!
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
    # 6.for playing
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
# 7. image saving
showPic = cv2.imwrite("filename.jpg",frame)
print(showPic)
print(cv2.__version__)

# 8. shutdown the camera
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: `kill $(pidof nameof.py)` (where `nameof.py` is whatever you named your python script)

Comment: script name 2.py , I tried  `kill $(pi4 2.py)` and  `kill $(piof4 2.py)` in location [pic](https://ibb.co/xJZ2sQJ), but still not stop execute though

Comment: Why not `kill $(pidof 2.py)`? You can confirm the name you need to kill with `ps axf | grep 2.py` and confirm that `pidof` finds the script by simply running `pidof 2.py` and seeing if a PID is returned.